# How to click on all the link of a site without duplication with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to scrape all the page of a website, and click on all the link clickable of the site without clicking 2 times on a link.
and i want to stay on the site, i mean not to click on facebook link of the site.

i try this:

```
id = "nameOfSite"
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href*="%s"]' % id).click()
```

Comment: Use httplib. Use selenium to take the links on the webpage make an list and pass that list to http client and verify the responses.

Comment: Add the html or the url

Answer (score 0):

One solution is: Store all the links in the page in `set`. The reason to store the URL's in the `set` is that it will store only unique values. Redundancy is avoided. Then loop through the `set` using `foreach` and perform CTRL+click action. This operation will open the link in new tab. So, you will stay in the current page. Please find below the sample code snippet.

```
List<WebElement> allUrls = <locator to get all the urls>;
// Converting List to Set
Set<WebElement> uniqueUrls = new HashSet<WebElement>(allUrls);
for(WebElement eachUrl : uniqueUrls) {
    eachUrl.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer is not in Python